# Is programming by voice possible

Tags: speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I've recently started to get pain in my arms and I was wondering if programming using voice software would be possible. I've used dragon naturally speaking several years ago but it was clunky and didnt really work too well with my ide at the time (netbeans)

Does anyone have any experience with programming by voice and if so, what software they would recommend

Comment: Voice recognition would mean no intellisense. Good luck!

Comment: I'm very curious if this exists too. Unfortunately what I've seen with Dragon makes it fairly unlikely that it would be an easy solution.

Comment: @KirkWoll: Yeah, but try to tell the machine that you mean account and not Account. Or try to make it understand that the variable you want is IsAccValid2Disp ^^

Comment: @Matthieu, ah *case*!  Good point, that'll be a true deal-breaker.

Comment: We need brain to computer interfaces. That'll solve all the problems. It's the 21st century!

Comment: Yes it is possible and efficient and autocomplete still works just fine: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8SkdfdXWYaI

Answer (score 3):

Speech-recognition software would probably take an absolute *age* to program with, at least by comparison - consider all that spoken-out punctuation, and those names consisting of concatenated and/or abbreviated words...

Consider other options, such as [Dasher](http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/dasher/), for text input.  Dasher's particularly neat because it "learns" what you write with it and starts making likely next characters easier to get to.

Also consider taking steps to reduce the strain on your arms and hands *without* stopping typing.  Using an ergonomic keyboard can make a lot of difference, as can changing layouts to, say, [Colemak](http://colemak.com/) or [Programmer Dvorak](http://www.kaufmann.no/roland/dvorak/) - tthe latter is particularly good for programming, as it makes a lot of the non-alphanumerics we use a lot in programming more easily available (if you're doing strings of digits you should really be using the numpad anyway...).  Also consider using a break-enforcer such as [Workrave](http://www.workrave.org/) to avoid and/or recover from RSI.

Comment: There's a book out there called "stretching". It has a lot of stretches for sitting at a desk. The book was written in the 70's but has been updated in the 90's. Also, doctors can help with specific stretches that can reduce muscle pain.

Comment: have you used dasher for programming?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried voice recognition addon for chrome, it is good for simple searches, but when i tried to search words which are alike it failed most times. Voice programming is possible for LOLCODE where it is simple words or brainfuck where are just few commands. I cant imagine using voice recogntion for C sharp in VS or Java, where you can have limitless amout of libraries and classes.